# Azure Pipelines -> Multi configuration builds -> fail a build only if all configurations failed

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm using the Multi configuration job feature in Azure Pipelines, and I wanted to know if there's a way to configure the pipeline so if one of the configurations succeeds, the build will continue to the next job, but if *all* configurations fail, then the build will be marked as failed and won't proceed.

Comment: Can you share more details about your current configuration?

Comment: Hi Friend, may I know if you have any update on this ticket?